# How to fix appxmanifest.xml for xbox one?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, unity-game-engine, xbox, xbox-one, appxmanifest

I am currently getting this error for a game I'm working on for the xbox one. It runs perfectly fine thought unity5 and when I exported it as a .exe game for pc but I can't get it to run locally or remotely. I have it set to debug x64 since that's what it says on it needs to be on to run one the xbox one.

---

```
OUTPUT CODE

    Restoring NuGet packages...
To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
1>------ Build started: Project: Assembly-CSharp, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Assembly-CSharp-firstpass, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>  Assembly-CSharp-firstpass -> C:\Users\david\Desktop\Speed Runner\UWP\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass\bin\x64\Debug\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll
1>  Assembly-CSharp -> C:\Users\david\Desktop\Speed Runner\UWP\Assembly-CSharp\bin\x64\Debug\Assembly-CSharp.dll
3>------ Build started: Project: Speed Runner, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
3>  UnityInstallationDir "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor".
3>  UnityWSAPlayerDir "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\MetroSupport".
3>  UnityProjectDir "C:\Users\david\Desktop\Speed Runner".
3>  Copying unprocessed assemblies...
3>  Running AssemblyConverter...
3>  AssemblyConverter done.
3>  Speed Runner -> C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\bin\x64\Debug\Speed Runner.exe
3>  Running Code Analysis...
3>MSBUILD : warning CA1707: Microsoft.Naming : Remove the underscores from namespace name 'Speed_Runner'.
3>MSBUILD : warning CA2210: Microsoft.Design : Sign 'Speed Runner.exe' with a strong name key.
3>MSBUILD : warning CA1014: Microsoft.Design : Mark 'Speed Runner.exe' with CLSCompliant(true) because it exposes externally visible types.
3>MSBUILD : warning CA1001: Microsoft.Design : Implement IDisposable on 'App' because it creates members of the following IDisposable types: 'AppCallbacks'. If 'App' has previously shipped, adding new members that implement IDisposable to this type is considered a breaking change to existing consumers.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\App.xaml.cs(56): warning CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of 'string.Format(string, object)' could vary based on the current user's locale settings, replace this call in 'App.OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs)' with a call to 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])'. If the result of 'string.Format(IFormatProvider, string, params object[])' will be displayed to the user, specify System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as the 'IFormatProvider' parameter. Otherwise, if the result will be stored and accessed by software, such as when it is persisted to disk or to a database, specify System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\App.xaml.cs(51): warning CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'App.OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs)', validate parameter 'args' before using it.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\App.xaml.cs(71): warning CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'App.OnFileActivated(FileActivatedEventArgs)', validate parameter 'args' before using it.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\App.xaml.cs(92): warning CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs)', validate parameter 'args' before using it.
3>MSBUILD : warning CA1051: Microsoft.Design : Because field 'App.splashScreen' is visible outside of its declaring type, change its accessibility to private and add a property, with the same accessibility as the field has currently, to provide access to it.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\MainPage.xaml.cs(140): warning CA1024: Microsoft.Design : Change 'MainPage.GetSwapChainPanel()' to a property if appropriate.
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\MainPage.xaml.cs(73): warning CA1062: Microsoft.Design : In externally visible method 'MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs)', validate parameter 'e' before using it.
3>  Code Analysis Complete -- 0 error(s), 11 warning(s)
3>C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml : error APPX0501: Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 37, Column 20, Reason: 'windows.fileTypeAssociation' violates enumeration constraint of 'windows.backgroundTasks windows.preInstalledConfigTask windows.updateTask windows.restrictedLaunch'. The attribute 'Category' with value 'windows.fileTypeAssociation' failed to parse.
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

```
ERROR CODE

    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 37, Column 20, Reason: 'windows.fileTypeAssociation' violates enumeration constraint of 'windows.backgroundTasks windows.preInstalledConfigTask windows.updateTask windows.restrictedLaunch'. The attribute 'Category' with value 'windows.fileTypeAssociation' failed to parse.    Speed Runner    C:\Users\david\Desktop\test games\speed runner\Speed Runner\bin\x64\Debug\AppxManifest.xml
```

---

```
AppManifest.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:build="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/appx/2015/build">
  <!--
    THIS PACKAGE MANIFEST FILE IS GENERATED BY THE BUILD PROCESS.

    Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.

    For more information on package manifest files, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=241727
  -->
  <Identity Name="SpeedRunner" Publisher="CN=osbodav gaming" Version="1.0.0.0" ProcessorArchitecture="x64" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="b893210b-2006-4704-91d6-aad428b34a24" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Speed Runner</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>osbodav gaming</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.scale-100.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.10240.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14295.0" />
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" MinVersion="14.0.23816.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="EN-US" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="Speed Runner.exe" EntryPoint="SpeedRunner.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Speed Runner" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" Description="Speed Runner" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile ShortName="Speed Runner" Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" BackgroundColor="#222C37" />
        <uap:InitialRotationPreference>
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscape" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="landscapeFlipped" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portrait" />
          <uap:Rotation Preference="portraitFlipped" />
        </uap:InitialRotationPreference>
      </uap:VisualElements>
      <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <FileTypeAssociation Name="game" />
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>UnityEngineDelegates.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="UnityEngineDelegates.PlatformInvoke" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="UnityEngineDelegates.FunctionDefsDictionary" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>UnityPlayer.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="UnityPlayer.XamlPageAutomationPeer" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="UnityPlayer.AppCallbacks" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
      <InProcessServer>
        <Path>CLRHost.dll</Path>
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.MethodTools" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.WinRTBridge" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.Marshalling" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.GCHandles" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.ExceptionHandling" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.Utils" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.UnityEngineObjectTools" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.ArrayTools" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.GCHandledObjects" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.ScriptingPinnedArray" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.TypeInformation" ThreadingModel="both" />
        <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="WinRTBridge.ObjectInstantiation" ThreadingModel="both" />
      </InProcessServer>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
  <build:Metadata>
    <build:Item Name="TargetFrameworkMoniker" Value=".NETCore,Version=v5.0" />
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudio" Version="14.0" />
    <build:Item Name="VisualStudioEdition" Value="Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015" />
    <build:Item Name="OperatingSystem" Version="10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)" />
    <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Build.AppxPackage.dll" Version="14.0.25123.0" />
    <build:Item Name="ProjectGUID" Value="{13A45C13-3265-47B8-BC48-A553B569DF55}" />
    <build:Item Name="ilc.exe" Version="1.2.23413.00 built by: PROJECTNREL" />
    <build:Item Name="OptimizingToolset" Value="ilc.exe" />
    <build:Item Name="UseDotNetNativeSharedAssemblyFrameworkPackage" Value="true" />
    <build:Item Name="Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks.dll" Version="14.0.25123.0" />
    <build:Item Name="WindowsMobile" Version="10.0.14295.0" />
  </build:Metadata>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear here: `'windows.fileTypeAssociation' violates enumeration constraint of 'windows.backgroundTasks windows.preInstalledConfigTask windows.updateTask windows.restrictedLaunch'. The attribute 'Category' with value 'windows.fileTypeAssociation' failed to parse.`

This means there's an attribute named `Category` that has the value `windows.fileTypeAssociation` and this value isn't one of the allowed values. There's only one element in your manifest with such an attribute:

```
<Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
  <FileTypeAssociation Name="game" />
</Extension>
```

The error message is essentially saying this element isn't allowed in the manifest. The obvious solution to your problem would be to remove this element from the `AppManifest.xml` file, but this won't work as the file itself warns you:

```
THIS PACKAGE MANIFEST FILE IS GENERATED BY THE BUILD PROCESS.

Changes to this file will be lost when it is regenerated. To correct errors in this file, edit the source .appxmanifest file.
```

So you need to modify the file with the `.appxmanifest` extension that `AppManifest.xml` was generated from. It's probably named something like `package.appxmanifest`.

Comment: thanks for the help had no idea that file was even there